# Clicking an image gives an incremented value in knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The following are the html and JS code

HTML body.

```
    <h2 data-bind="text: currentCat().name" id="cat-name"></h2>
    <div data-bind="text: currentCat().clickCount" id="cat-count"></div>
    <img src="" data-bind="click: incrementCount(), attr: {src: currentCat().imgSrc}" id="cat-img" alt="cute cat">
    <h4>NickNames</h4>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: currentCat().nickNames">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="js/lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

JS code

```
 var ViewModel = function() {
    this.currentCat = ko.observable( new Cat() );
    console.log(this.currentCat().clickCount())
    this.incrementCount = function(){


this.currentCat().clickCount(this.currentCat().clickCount() + 1);
    };
}

var Cat = function() {
    this.clickCount = ko.observable(0);
    this.name = ko.observable('Tabby');
    this.imgSrc = ko.observable('tabby.jpg');
    this.imgAttribution = ko.observable('XXXX');

    this.nickNames = ko.observableArray(
        [
            {name: 'Tabtab'},
            {name: 'T-bone'},
            {name: 'Mr. T'},
            {name: 'Tabitha Tab Tabby'}
        ]
    );
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

However, on rendering the HTML page, the click count is 1 instead of the expected value 0. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) expects a function reference, not an expression to run. The expression you've provided is run right away, when the binding is initialized. You need to change your binding to provide the function itself:

```
data-bind="click: incrementCount"
```

Comment: Ah that works ..!! So incrementCount() is run while initializing..!!